# 10 Years of Movies & TV

Tags: discussion

On November 30th the Movies & TV Stack Exchange celebrates its 10th anniversary! We'd like to thank this community for making this site the great place it is for discussing films and TV-shows. What was your favourite moment during those last 10 years?

Maybe you've been here for the past 10 years and have a wealth of highlights to share or maybe you joined yesterday because you had an urgent question and look forward to the next 10 years now. Tell us why you're here and what makes this place great. This could be a question you had for years and finally got answered, an answer you put all your expertise about your favourite film into, a comment that enlightened you in ways you never could imagine...

Answer (score 6):

I was not there for a whole decade but yeah Movies & TV hold the biggest place in my heart in the SE network. I joined during the beta site as a confused user and won the first election and with the support of the co-mods and fellow users, it went so smoothly. My understanding of the SE network was mostly due to M&TV only.

I never wanted to leave moderating my favorite site but due to lack of time and personal stress I was not able to do that moment and happy to see the current team did a great job. I will be happy to join back if the need comes.

Even as a user I loved researching for answers, asking my queries, and reading interesting posts. I wish this site see more and more successful decades.

I hope we can do some activities/competitions on the 10th anniversary. If SE can help to organize or just by rep-bounties which I can help giving off.

Answer (score 5):

I really enjoyed being a mod here, life just got in the way and I couldn't commit the amount of time I felt necessary for the role here.

Answer (score 3):

After watching a movie, I usually go to SE Movies to see what questions were asked. It usually helps to uncover some details I did not notice when watching (or sometimes a backstory). So plenty o great moments overall

<sub>... and a big let-down when "identify this movie" questions were banned :(</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Stack Exchange is my getaway. It is filled with people who have things in common with me and can have a discussion on it. I appreciate the creators of the amazing site. This isn't just a Q&A site. It is a place to expand my knowledge on thing I love and meet others who like the same thing. I may have only been her for about a year, but this will always be one of my favorite locations. Thanks for allowing me to be a part of this wonderful creation! **To many more years of Stack Exchange.**